# Buffer overflow in fread and strncpy in C++

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

I'm getting buffer overflow case from the appscan for the below set of code.
I'm not sure what is wrong in it.
If someone suggest a solution that would be great. Common Code is for all the platform.

```
int main()
{
   char* src = NULL;
   char* chenv = getenv("HOME");
   if (chenv == NULL || strlen(chenv) == 0)
       return -1;
   else
   {
       int len = strlen(chenv);
       src = new char[len+1];
       strncpy(src, chenv, len); // AppScan throws buffer overflow
       src[len+1]='\0';
   }
   FILE* fp;
   char content[4096];
   int len = 0;
   fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
   if(fp)
   {
       while( (len = fread(content, sizeof(char), sizeof(content), fp))> 0) // AppScan throws buffer overflow on content
       {
           docopy(content, len);// External funtion call. 
       }
   }

   return 0;  
}
```

Comment: @Evg The code is using the C++ `new` operator, so I guess it's actually C++.

Comment: @IanAbbott, right...

Comment: `src[len+1]='\0';` should be `src[len]='\0';`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Tried that option as well. But still the overflow error remains.

Comment: Are you talking about HCL AppScan, or some other tool? What _specifically_ is the error? Those functions are both _vulnerable_ to overflows, so are you sure it's telling you the overflow actually happens, and not just that it's a riskl?

Comment: Actually, given Ian's comment - AppScan _should_ be complaining about the assignment rather than the `strncpy`. Either the error is in the wrong place, or it's just warning you about unsafe functions.

Comment: You could also change `strncpy(src, chenv, len);` to `strncpy(src, chenv, len+1);` to see if that stops it complaining. It might be hitting something similar to GCC's `-Wstringop-truncation` warning.

Comment: @Useless Yes I'm taking about the HCL AppScan only. In both the functions bufferoverflow Suspect on those two lines of code with CWE ID : 120 [link] (http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/120.html)

Comment: The `fread` call looks OK to me. I know nothing about HCL, but perhaps it wants you to replace `fread(content, sizeof(char), sizeof(content), fp)` with `fread(content, sizeof(char), sizeof(content)/sizeof(char), fp)`? (It shouldn't make any difference since `sizeof(char)` equals `1` by definition....)

Comment: I really dislike that stringop-truncation warning. Anyway, the simple solution to the first warning is to just use `std::string`, which you probably ought to be doing anyway. Agree that it isn't clear what its issue is with the `fread`. What happens if you just use plain `read`, or `std::istream::read` instead?

Comment: I don't understand the newfound popularity of `strncpy`. It's error-prone. In the code in the question, the size of the string being copied is known, a buffer that's large enough has been allocated, and `strcpy` would do exactly what's needed. That dance of `strncpy` with a length that's smaller than the actual buffer followed by filling in the nul terminator (even if the code was corrected to put it in the correct location) is pointless here.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `return -1;` is not portable. The only portable way to indicate a failure is `return EXIT_FAILURE;`. To indicate success, use either `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strncpy I tried using strdup() and the issue solved. But the fread is still having the issue.